# Wordpress URL not found

Tags: wordpress

OS Window

I have installed WordPress in my localhost.
My website is now finished. I have no problem with my menu and to reach my pages.

When i send online, if I try to reach my page, I have an error message :

The requested URL /page/ was not found on this server.

I am working on a Wordpress subscription website.

Thank you in advance,

Thibault Renard

Answer (score 0):

Are you install WP in your localhost, not in host?